# Docker - Yarn "There appears to be trouble with the npm registry (returned undefined). Retrying..." when running yarn install

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, yarnpkg

I have 3 containers, one for mySQL `db`, one for the nodejs `server`, and one for `client` (create-react-app). This error is occuring on the `client` container

Has been working previously until I tried to get everything set up for a production environment using Nginx in its own container (I've since deleted all the code that configures that, but the error still persists).

**The error:**

```
Step 9/12 : RUN yarn install
 ---> Running in 45145c591167
yarn install v1.22.19
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning @svgr/plugin-svgo > svgo > stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
info There appears to be trouble with the npm registry (returned undefined). Retrying...
```

It continues retrying until it eventually times out.

**Things I've tried so far:**

I've tried `docker system prune -a` and `docker volume prune` then running `docker-compose up` again, but it still fails.

I've also tried deleting `node_modules` and `yarn.lock`, still doesn't work.

If I try to create a new directory (outside of docker, just local on my pc), run `yarn init` and add all the dependencies into the `package.json` file, it installs correctly. So it appears to be an issue within my Docker containers.

**The Code**

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database_development
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
  client:
    container_name: client
    build: ./client
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
  server:
    container_name: server
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 4242:4242
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
```

`client` DockerFile

```
FROM node:16-alpine
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV ${NODE_ENV}

COPY package.json /app
RUN yarn install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

Comment: why aren't you passing lock file ?

Comment: I am copying over the lock file `COPY . .`, I deleted it right before running `docker compose up`, that's why it's showing no lock file. But regardless, ended up fixing this issue by `git revert`ing to before I made the changes and eventually got everything working. Not sure what this issue stemmed from though, haven't been able to reproduce.